# Can't see any network with wicd, wifi card seems to be desactivated

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have an Acer Aspire 7 A715-71G-75B3.
I recently installed Debian on it with `wicd`.
When I run `wicd-client`, I can't see any network displayed.

I think my WiFi card isn't activated (even though `rfkill` says otherwise, see the command at the end).
I should be able to activate it by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> but it's not working. On the other hand, the other key combination are working. (like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to put the PC in sleep mode)

I can't see any option to activate it from BIOS and the key combination is working on Windows (dual boot).

Is there any ways to activate it from the cmd line or something?

Here's the result of differents command I used already:

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5910 (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a171 (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c8d (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

`iwconfig` :

```
enp0s20f0u5  no wireless extensions.

enp3s0f1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig` :

```
enp0s20f0u5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.42.174  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.42.255
        inet6 fe80::54b4:f1ff:fe19:d293  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 56:b4:f1:19:d2:93  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 20769  bytes 20679799 (19.7 MiB)
        RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 2
        TX packets 19606  bytes 3078503 (2.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 98:29:a6:48:2a:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 492  bytes 39516 (38.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 492  bytes 39516 (38.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`rfkill` :

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Atheros QCA6174 is well supported. Two possibilities: 1. a conflicting module or 2. missing firmware.

Comment: How can i find out ?

Comment: I don't know much about this so I suggest you run this Ubuntu Forums script https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108 with an alternative internet connection (or run it offline) and add the results by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: You were rigth it was indeed a missing firmware.

Answer (score 2):

As MichealBay said in the comments of my original question it was a missing firmware.

Indeed, after running the script he talked about [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=370108).
I could see that the command dmesg returned this :

```
[    3.224796] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin (-2)
```

So I went to this [github](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/) and downloaded the following ath10k [archive](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/archive/master.zip).
Then I extracted the zip file to the folder :

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k
```

Wich I had to create.

Thenn in the both folders :

```
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/
/lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/
```

I had to rename the files :

```
hw2.1/firmware-5.bin_SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 to firmware-5.bin
hw3.0/firmware-4.bin_WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 to firmware-4.bin
```

After a reboot it was working fine.

Hope this will help.